# Tomcat 8 , how NIO is works

Tags: java, tomcat, nio

I want to understand how NIO works in tomcat.

I create Spring Boot MVC application with the following properties in `app.prop`

```
server.tomcat.max-connections = 80
server.tomcat.max-threads= 70
```

When application is started , I saw Live threads: 51 from `JVisualVM`

As I understand (from thread names) only 10 threads are from Tomcat connection pool (They have names like `http-nio-exec-1`).  Then using `wrk`I test my app using

```
 wrk -t12 -c400 -d30s http://localhost:8080
```

(12 threads and 400 connections)

Now Tomcat create 70 http nio connections , and when they are not active Tomcat kill 60 of them .

My question:

1)I began to learn NIO package in Java, and I know that server created by `ServerSocketChanel` can handle 1000 requests per seconds. Why Tomcat firtly create as many threads as we write in `max-threads` prop and only then use NIO concept

2) I don't clearly understand what is `server.tomcat.max-connections`

From docs: `The maximum number of connections that the server will accept and process at any given time. When this number has been reached, the server will accept, but not process, one further connection.`

But during the testing , I also open browser and I didn't wait for free connection

(from `wrk` I send 400 connections to server but I also was able to see web page in browser when I open localhost:8080)

Comment: It needs threads to process requests concurrently, even if those threads aren't doing the actual I/O.

Comment: Does `wrk` support HTTP keepalives? Are they enabled or disabled by default?